# Number of calls in a call center

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I need some help with this one. "The numbers of calls in a call center has the Poisson distribution. It is known that in a 6 days week the average number of calls is 12. What is the probability that on Tuesday there will be at least one call, given that in exactly 2 days during this week there was no call at all ? " I tried defining a Binomial random variable of number of days with no call at all (after calculating the probability of this event using Poisson distribution). I managed to find what I believe is the denominator of the solution, but I am stuck with the nominator. Can you please assist me with this problem ? Thank you !

Comment: The average number of calls is 12 for a (6-day) week or 12 for each day of a 6 days week?

Comment: 12 calls a week, 2 a day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Grinding it out:** Let $A$ be the event there was at least one call on Tuesday, and $B$ be the event there were exactly two days with no call. We want $\Pr(A\mid B)$. It is easier to think about $\Pr(A^c\mid B)$.

Let $p$ be the probability of no call on a particular day. You know how to find $p$.

Then the probability of exactly two call-free days in a "week" is $\binom{6}{2}p^2(1-p)^4$.

To finish calculating $\Pr(A^c\mid B)$, we need $\Pr(A^c\cap B)$. This is the probability of no call on Tuesday, times the probability exactly one of the other $5$ days is call-free. This is $p\binom{5}{1}p(1-p)^4$.

Divide. There is cancellation and we get $\frac{2}{6}$.

**Another way:** If there were two call-free days, the probability one of them was Tuesday is obviously $\frac{2}{6}$. So the conditional probability of at least one call on Tuesday is $\frac{4}{6}$.

Comment: +1 for the second way.  You do not need to know $p$ in the first way so long as it is neither $0$ nor $1$.

Comment: @satishramanathan:  Interpreting "two days" as not including Tuesday may be stretching things. If we do that, then conditioning makes no difference since the Poisson has a built-in assumption of independence, and the conditional probability of at least one call on Tuesday is $1-e^{-2}$.

Comment: @AndreNicolas, Yes Sir, Not reading the problem correctly when being a quasi student(old but not in school) has been my weakness.  Your second approach is great +1..  :))